# Magento extension shows white screen of death

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using Magento Community Edition ver. 1.9.0 and whenever I am trying to install any extension from Magento Connect it shows white screen of death. For example after installing Owebia-Shipping 2 extension it shows white screen on the front-end and on back-end too.

Comment: Have you checked the Magento logs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try after giving full permission to your magento folder.

Answer (score 0):

When PHP shows you a blank white browser screen in means a fatal error has happened prior to any `print` or `echo` statements.  If you temporarily set `display_errors` to `1` in `index.php` PHP should output the error.  Without this error you're just grasping at straws.